# Get the values of two fields from a table JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, join, field

I have a mysql table called `districts` where all the districts and their id's are stored. I have another table called `tbl_units` where unit details such as `office_address`, `office_district`, `factory_address`, `factory_district` are saved.

Now if want to get the names of the districts from their id's by JOIN ing the two tables, how should I write the query ? Because

```
SELECT u.*, d.district_name
FROM  tbl_unit_details as u,
    tbl_districts as d 
WHERE u.unit_id = '$unit_id' 
    AND u.district_id = d.district_id 
    AND u.factory_district_id = d.district_id 
ORDER BY unit_name
```

returns only the first , i.e. district name of office.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the districts table to the units table twice; once for each district type. Use aliases to distinguish each instance of the district table. If you like, you can include the optional `AS` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

try this out maybe it can help

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT u.*,t.* FROM districts as u,tbl_units as t WHERE u.id=t.id");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
//echo your required result however you want
```

here u.id represents districs table id and t.id represents tbl_units table id, but in this case your id for tbl_units must be a foreign key.