# how to get data from two tables Using JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, join

```
question
**question_id  question  option1 option2 option3 option4** 
    15          AAA         a1     a2      a3       a4
    38          BBB         b1     b2      b3       b4
    39          CCC         c1     c2      c3       c4
    44          DDD         d1     d2      d3       d4
    45          EEE         e1     e2      e3       e4

exam_question_list
**id**  **exam_paper_id** **category_id** **job_id**   **q1  q2  q3  q4  q5**
  1          1                    3         1            15  38  39  44   45
```

**MY query**
    $i=1;

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM exam_question_list eq 
LEFT JOIN question qu1 ON qu1.question_id =eq.q1 
LEFT JOIN question qu2 ON qu2.question_id =eq.q2 
LEFT JOIN question qu3 ON qu3.question_id =eq.q3 
LEFT JOIN question qu4 ON qu4.question_id =eq.q4 
LEFT JOIN question qu5 ON qu5.question_id =eq.q5";

$result=mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql); ?>
    <table>

<?php 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>
    <tr>
     <tr data-label="Question"><td><input name="q<?php echo $i++; ?>" value="<?php  echo $row['question'];?>" readonly /></td></tr>
      <tr data-label="Question"><td><input type="radio"  name="a" value="1"/><?php echo $row['option1']; ?></td></tr>
      <tr data-label="Question"><td><input type="radio"  name="a" value="2"/><?php echo $row['option2']; ?></td></tr>
      <tr data-label="Question"><td><input type="radio"  name="a" value="3"/><?php echo $row['option3']; ?></td></tr>
      <tr data-label="Question"><td><input type="radio"  name="a" value="4"/><?php echo $row['option4']; ?></td></tr>  

    </tr>   
<?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

This gives only the last question(q5) only. I want to display the q1,q2,q3,q4,q5 question and its options separately. How to do that?

Comment: have a look at [ https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-create-dynamic-table-in-php-data-is-coming-from-database-mysql/5311/3 ]

Comment: where are q1 through q5 coming from? do you have columns in the first table that are named that?

Comment: FOREIGN KEY (q1) REFERENCES question(question_id), FOREIGN KEY (q2) REFERENCES question(question_id), FOREIGN KEY (q3) REFERENCES question(question_id), FOREIGN KEY (q4) REFERENCES question(question_id), FOREIGN KEY (q5) REFERENCES question(question_id),

Comment: Update my answer check now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aliases to distinguish each instance of the question table. If you like, you can include the optional `AS` keyword.

```
SELECT * FROM exam_question_list AS eq 
LEFT JOIN question AS qu1 ON qu1.question_id =eq.q1 
LEFT JOIN question AS qu2 ON qu2.question_id =eq.q2 
LEFT JOIN question AS qu3 ON qu3.question_id =eq.q3 
LEFT JOIN question AS qu4 ON qu4.question_id =eq.q4 
LEFT JOIN question AS qu5 ON qu5.question_id =eq.q5
```

Source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18120317/4511459)

In get Options too

```
SELECT *,question.option1,question.option2,question.option3,question.option4 FROM exam_question_list AS eq 
LEFT JOIN question AS qu1 ON qu1.question_id =eq.q1 
LEFT JOIN question AS qu2 ON qu2.question_id =eq.q2 
LEFT JOIN question AS qu3 ON qu3.question_id =eq.q3 
LEFT JOIN question AS qu4 ON qu4.question_id =eq.q4 
LEFT JOIN question AS qu5 ON qu5.question_id =eq.q5
```

Comment: can give an example, I can't understand. How to use 'As' keyword, can give some link of example

Comment: Query is ok. But still I can't get the all questions, options into the page, what is the error in while loop? how can I preview the q1-q5 all 5 questions with options.

Comment: So you need to get all from question table also?

Comment: not all, question, option1,option2,option3,option4 from 'question' table

Comment: Try This code `SELECT * FROM question AS q 
LEFT JOIN exam_question_list AS eq ON eq.q1 = q.question_id AND eq.q2 = q.question_id AND eq.q3 = q.question_id AND eq.q4 = q.question_id AND eq.q5 = q.question_id`

Comment: 'question' table has so many questions.It is a question pool. So the above query gives all the questions in 'question' table

Comment: GEt the error, Unknown column 'question.option1' in 'field list'

Comment: add question in select from